# Lets say i have a function $f(x^2 - 5) = e^x$ If i were to find $f'(3)$, how do I find the value of $x$ that i need to plug in?

Tags: calculus

Using chain rule I can determine that $h'(x) = f'(x^2 - 5)*2x$ , but for the value of $f'(3)$ plugging in 3 does not seem right.

Comment: You will need to find the value $x$ so that $x^2-5=3$.

Comment: Are you given a set of $x$ for which that equation is valid?  (For example, it's impossible for the equation to be true both for $x=1$ and for $x=-1$, or it would imply $f(-4) = e^1$ and $f(4) = e^{-1}$ giving a contradiction.)

Comment: Yes, I did not type the exact function in the post but it only works for the positive value. Thanks.

Comment: I would do this: $\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)\:=\frac{d}{dx}\left(f\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\right)\:+\frac{d}{dx}\left(g\left(x\right)\right)\:=e^x\:+2x$. From here you can follow @Gedgar

Comment: Would it not be $e^x$ * 2x instead of + 2x since it's chain rule?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for this to be well-defined, $x$ must be restricted to the  nonnegative [or non-positive] reals. Indeed, otherwise, one could have $f(x^2-5)=e^x$ or $f(x^2-5)=e^{-x}$, as $x^2-5=(-x)^2-5$.

Let us assume then that $x$ is restricted to the nonnegative reals. Then, write $u=x^2-5$. But then $u=x^2-5;$ $x \ge 0;$ $\implies$ $x$ $=$ $\sqrt{u+5}$. Thus the original equation becomes
$$f(u) \ = \ e^{\sqrt{u+5}}.$$ [**If $x$ were instead restricted to the nonpositives** the original equation would become $$f(u) \ = \ e^{-\sqrt{u+5}}.]$$

Next, we need to be clear on what is being asked here: $\frac{df}{du}\Big|_{u=3}$ $=$ $\frac{d(e^{\sqrt{u+5}})}{du}\Big|_{u=3}$.

Can you take it from here.

Answer (score -2):

To find $f(3)$ from $f(x^2- 5)= e^x$, let $3= x^2- 5$ so that $x=\sqrt8$ or $x= -\sqrt{8}$ so that $f(3)= e^{\sqrt8}$ or $f(3)= e^{-\sqrt8}$.

Comment: It's f'(3) not f(3)